# Magento Request IndexController

Tags: magento

What is the first IndexController in Magento that is triggered if a request was made to the shop?

Comment: Found out that the IndexController that is called for the first request (home) is Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction(), because the homepage is a CMS page.

Comment: It's a configuration setting. Ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102373/833795

Answer (score 2):

The architecture of Magento will look like this... http://alanstorm.com/2009/img/magento-book/php-mvc.png

For more, have a look at this http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world

Answer (score 1):

```
<global>

    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <tibdev_seo_page_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Tibdev_Seo_Model_Page_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkForEndingSlash</method>
                </tibdev_seo_page_observer>
            </observers>

        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>

</global>
```

Now i am using the controller_action_predispatch Event and it is working.
THX guys!